# Is there a difference between theorem proof and theorem demonstration?

Tags: proof-verification, terminology

When referring to proving that a theorem is true, I have seen both words used interchangeably. Do they mean the same thing ?

Comment: A demonstration to me is an application, i.e., putting the theorem to work, as opposed to showing why it works.

Comment: i ask this because in my language we only use demonstration and i never heard the equivalent of the word proof used in math

Comment: @yoyo_fun, in Portuguese, the term "demonstration" ("demonstração") is also used in place of "proof".  It seems to be the case of all latin languages.

Answer (score 7):

In English, *proof* and *demonstration* have different connotations, as Théophile points out.  A demonstration might be an application or “illustration” of a method.  I believe most native English speakers would use *proof*.

But in some other languages, the word cognate to *demonstration* is what is used for proof.  The letters QED, commonly appearing after a proof, are initials for the Latin phrase *quod erat demonstrandum*.  In French, they say *ce qu'il fallait démontrer*.  But in German, the word for “to prove” is *beweisen* rather than *demonstrieren* (and *prüfen* is to test!)