# Proof vs Demonstration

Tags: terminology, meta-math

In metamathematics, what convention is used to distinguish an informal proof *about* the system and a formal proof *in* the system?

I'd like to reserve "proof" for the object language, what should I write under a meta-theorem?

Comment: See the post [Is there a difference between theorem proof and theorem demonstration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2057072/is-there-a-difference-between-theorem-proof-and-theorem-demonstration)

Comment: No "strict convention" available : sometimes, *derivation* is used for the proof *in* the system.